# Добавление атрибутa muted к тегу <audio> через JavaScript

Tags: javascript

пытался через js добавить атрибут 'muted' к аудио тегу, но попытки тщетны.
При просмотре элементов все работает, но на деле же музыка продолжает играть, в чем причина?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
(function () {

    var mouseTimer;
    function mouseDown() {
        mouseUp();
        mouseTimer = window.setTimeout(execMouseDown, 1500);
    }

    function mouseUp() {
        if (mouseTimer) window.clearTimeout(mouseTimer);
    }

    function execMouseDown() {

        **function kpssaudio() {
            document.querySelector('#kpssaudio').setAttribute('muted', '');
        }
        kpssaudio();**

    }

    var div = document.getElementById("oxx");
    div.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
    document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);

}());
```

```html
 <audio id="kpssaudio" preload="auto" loop="">
      <source type="audio/mp3" src="assets/stuff/music.mp3">
  </audio>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам поможет установка свойства `muted` у [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

```
document.querySelector('#kpssaudio').muted = true;
```

```js
window.addEventListener('click',function(){
  document.querySelector('audio').muted = !document.querySelector('audio').muted;
})
```

```html
<audio controls>
 <source src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/oswkgcw749xc8xs/The-Noisy-Freaks.mp3?dl=1" type="audio/mp3">
  <source src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/75jpngrgnavyu7f/The-Noisy-Freaks.ogg?dl=1" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<br><br>
click anywhere to mute
```

Comment: Гений, огромное спасибо снова)

Comment: @SkyLikeIT всегда пожалуйста